# Verificar a ocorrencia de cada letra em uma string - C

Tags: c

Preciso escrever um procedimento que receba um ponteiro para uma string p e mostre(imprima)o número de ocorrências de cada letra dentro da palavra.
Exemplo: arara deve mostrar a=3 e r=2
         sapato deve mostrar s=1, a=2, t=1 e o=1

estava tentando pensar em uma logica em C Puro mas não consigo. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Defina um array de inteiros com tamanho suficiente para cada letra do alfabeto (letra[27]) e inicialize com 0. Percorra sua string, caractere a caractere, e aproveitando uma particularidade do C faça: letra[tplower(palavra[i]) - 'a']++. Ao final imprima cada elemento de letra que seja diferente de zero. Para saber qual é a letra é só somar 'a' ao índice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void procedure (char *palavra){
    int cont, x=0, cont2;
    char letra;

    for (cont=0; cont<strlen(palavra); cont++){
        letra=palavra[cont];
        for (cont2=0; cont2<strlen(palavra); cont2++){
            if(letra==palavra[cont2]){
                x++;
            }
        }
        printf ("\nocorrencias da letra %c = %d", letra, x);    
        x=0;
    }
}

main(){

    char word[20];
    char *p = word;
    printf ("Digite uma palavra: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(p);
    procedure(p);
}
```

Comment: Evite responder apenas com código. Explique um pouco a sua solução.

Answer (score 0):

void verificarRepeticao(char [],int);

void verificarExistencia(char [],char, int *);

int main(){

```
int const quantodadeElementos = 50;
char vetorPalavra[quantodadeElementos];

printf("Informe uma palavra: ");
scanf("%s", vetorPalavra);

verificarRepeticao(vetorPalavra,quantodadeElementos);

return 0;
```

}

void verificarRepeticao(char vetorPalavra[], int quantidadeElementos){

```
int contador = 0, i = 0, j = 0, teste = 0;
char charVerificaAtual, vetorPalavraDois[quantidadeElementos];

for(i=0;i<quantidadeElementos;i++){
    vetorPalavraDois[i] = '\0';
}

for(i=0;vetorPalavra[i]!='\0';i++){
    charVerificaAtual = vetorPalavra[i];
    verificarExistencia(vetorPalavraDois,charVerificaAtual,&teste);
    if(teste == 1){

    }else if(teste == 0){
        for(j=0;vetorPalavra[j]!='\0';j++){
            if(charVerificaAtual == vetorPalavra[j]){
                contador++;
            }
        }
    vetorPalavraDois[i]=charVerificaAtual;
    printf("%c Ocorreu %d.\n", charVerificaAtual,contador);
    contador = 0;
    teste = 0;

    }
}
```

}
void verificarExistencia(char vetorPalavraDois[], char charVerificaAtual, int *teste){

```
int i=0, testedois = 0;

for(i=0;vetorPalavraDois[i] != '\0';i++){
    if(charVerificaAtual == vetorPalavraDois[i]){
        testedois = 1;
        break;
    }
}
*teste = testedois;
```

}